# Display a custom button on WooCommerce product pages only for certain categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I have added a custom button to product page that is connected to product meta demo_url, which is just an URL that changes by each product (to open live demo for each product separately in a lightbox). The code is quite simple:

```
function my_extra_button_on_product_page() {
  global $product;
  $demo_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'demo_url', true );
  echo '<a class="fancybox iframe" data-width="1280" data-height="720" href="'.$demo_url.'"><button style="background: lightblue; padding-left: 19px; padding-right: 19px;">Przymierz</button></a>';
}
```

The thing is, there are some other products in the shop that do not use live demo function. They are listed in different categories. I would like this button to be visible ONLY for certain product category (or invisible for two product categories - whatever is easier).

I suppose this should be done via get_cat_ID( $cat_name ), but I am unsure how to write the if function and generally I'm quite inexperienced in coding. Maybe something like this could work?

```
if get_cat_ID( $cat_name ) = categoryname {
    echo 'button code';
else
    echo 'no button code';
endif
}
```

How can I make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with the hooked function below, defining in it all your needed product categories:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_button_by_categories', 32 ,0 );
function custom_button_by_categories(){
    
    global $product;

    // Define your categories in this array (can be Ids, slugs or names)
    $product_cats = array('clothing', 'music', 'furnitures');

    if( has_term( $product_cats, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
         $demo_url = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'demo_url', true );
         echo '<a class="fancybox iframe" data-width="1280" data-height="720" href="'.$demo_url.'"><button style="background: lightblue; padding-left: 19px; padding-right: 19px;">Przymierz</button></a>';
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The button will appear below "add to cart" button for your defined categories. You don't need to customize any template.

If you want to remove add-to-cart button on that categories (to keep your custom button only, you can add in the condition this line:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30, 0);
```

All code is tested and works in WooCommerce version 3+